# Error List 'listName01' does not exist at site with URL https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com'. in Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, error, modern-experience

I have been trying to use Postman to see list items using Postman and I am getting following error:

```
List 'listName01' does not exist at site with URL https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com'
```

When I log in SharePoint in browser, I can see list and I can add items to the list. There re no spaces in list name. However, when hit below URL, I am still getting same issue.

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName01')
```

I am not sure what am I missing here?

Is there any permission I need to provide to my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint REST API `lists/GetByTitle()` endpoint, you have to pass the **Display name** of list & not the name in list URL.

**Example**:

In below image, you can see the display name of list is "Logo Universe" while URL is like `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/Lists/ImageList/AllItems.aspx`.

So, in REST endpoint you will use display name of list like:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Logo Universe')/items
```

[image]

---

Also, make sure you are using correct site URL in REST endpoint where list is created.

---

**Additional**:

Another way to get list items is using GUID of SharePoint list like:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists(guid'{list_guid}')/items
```

**Example**:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b778bbec-dd69-4a6c-9437-c73972c36292')/items
```

You can get GUID of list from **list settings** page URL.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, using full list URL mentioned by you resolved my issue. However, I am not able to see any list item in my postman. It shows empty. Any reason for that? (I can see 1 record in sharepoint list)